# How to modify the numerical decimals of my API fetches?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I need the numerical data that the API returns to have two decimal places instead of three, that is, if it gives me a number: 140,444 it will be 140,44

What should I modify?

```
function fetchData() {
     fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")
       .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
     })
    .then((data) => {
      const filteredOutput = data.filter((item) => {
        switch (item.casa.nombre) {
          case "Dolar Blue":
            return item;
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      });
      let html = "";
      filteredOutput.forEach((item) => {
        html +=
          '<p class= "venta">  <small class= "ventaPrecio">VENTA</small><span</span><br>  $ ' +
          item.casa.venta +
          "</p>";
      });

      document
        .querySelector("#blueVenta")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
}
         fetchData();
```

Comment: Use toFixed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

you can use .toFixed()

ex:

```
54433.6559943.toFixed(4) // will console 54433.6560
```

Comment: When I add in:   return item.toFixed(2);
stop showing me the result. I already tried, I don't know where to insert it in my code

Comment: you need to add it to the number itself lets say item.casa.nombre = 45.22222
you should do tem.casa.nombre.toFixed(2)

Comment: Actually I already tried to add it directly to the number, but it does not run an error but the number disappears. It's weird, I can't understand the problem :(